# Why am I getting error while sending PUT request to the server?

Tags: node.js, express, rest, backend

I have created two files namely productController and productRouter for creating my endpoints. Post and get(all products) are working well. But delete, put, and get(single product) are not working. Only Html code is displayed on postman. here is my productController

```
const Product = require("../models/productModel");
//create product --admin
exports.createProduct = async (req,res,next)=>{
    const product = await Product.create(req.body);
    res.status(201).json({
        success:true,
        product
    })
}
//get All Products
exports.getAllProducts = async (req,res)=>{
  const products =  await Product.find();
    res.status(200).json({success:true,products})
}
//get product details 
exports.getProduct = async(productId)=>{
    const product =  await Product.findById(productId);
    if(!product){
        return res.status(500).json({success:false,message:"Not found"})
        }
            return product
}

//update product --admin
exports.updateProduct = async (req, res, next) => {
    let product = await Product.findById(req.params.id);
    if(!product){
    return res.status(500).json({success:false,message:"Not found"})
    }
    product = await Product.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, {
        new: true,
        runValidators: true,
        useFindAndModify: false,
      });
    
      res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        product,
      });
    }; //not working

//delete 
exports.deleteProduct = async(productId)=>{
    var data=await Product.findByIdAndDelete(productId)
    return data
}
```

here is my productRouter

```
const express = require("express");
const { getAllProducts,createProduct, updateProduct, deleteProduct, getProduct } = require("../controllers/productController");
const router = express.Router();
router.route("/products").get(getAllProducts)
router.route("/product/new").post(createProduct)
router.route("product/:id").put(updateProduct)
router.delete("/product/:id",async(req,res)=>{
    var {id}=req.params
    res.json(await deleteProduct(id))
});
router.get("/product/:id", async (req, res) => {
    var { id } = req.params;
    var products = await getProduct(id);
    res.json(products);
});

module.exports = router
```

I am working on backend only, haven't started with frontend
*your text*

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: My request is not working. The postman is just displaying the html code saying cannot put.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting the error like `Cannot PUT`, it means that you are sending the request on an api which doesn't exist.
After looking at your code, i found that you are missing the slash in the beginning of put request.

Just add the slash and it will work.

```
router.route("/product/:id").put(updateProduct)
```